How can you get Bloomberg BQNT syntax (BQL) outside of the Terminal?
This used to be possible (see this post: How get BQL (bLOOMBERG) query from python) however I can't get it work now. I am stuck on the following AttributeError after copying numerous packages/files: "zmq.eventloop' has no attribute 'ioloop'" which if I read, is because I am trying to get access outside of the sandboxed, Terminal version. Has anyone figured out a way to use BQL in python locally? Thanks - complete traceback below:
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent 
call last)
Cell In[4], line 4
    1 import pandas as pd
    2 import bql
----> 4 bq = bql.Service()
    5 query = """get(px_last)for('AAPL US EQUITY')with(dates=range(-1y,0d),fill='prev')"""
    6 data = bql.combined_df(bq.execute(query)).reset_index()

File c:\Users\user\OneDrive\python311\Lib\site-packages\bql\service.py:306, in Service.__init__(self, metadata_reader, request_executor, preferences, query_parser)
    295 """Construct a new Service object.
    296 
    297 Specify `preferences` if you want certain preferences applied to each
(...)
    302 precedence over the global preferences specified here.
    303 """
    304 self.__bqapi_session = None
    305 self.__metadata_reader = (metadata_reader or
--> 306                           self.__create_metadata_reader())
    307 self._request_executor = (request_executor or
    308                           self.__create_request_executor())
    309 self._query_parser = query_parser or self.__create_query_parser()

File c:\Users\user\OneDrive\python311\Lib\site-packages\bql\service.py:324, in Service.__create_metadata_reader(self)
    322 def __create_metadata_reader(self):
    323     factory = MetadataReaderFactory()
--> 324     return factory.create_metadata_reader()

File c:\Users\user\OneDrive\python311\Lib\site-packages\bqlmetadata\metadata_reader_factory.py:63, in MetadataReaderFactory.create_metadata_reader(self)
    60 def create_metadata_reader(self):
    61     import bqapi
---> 63     bqapi_session = bqapi.get_session_singleton()
    65     bqhopper_breg_value = _get_bqhopper_enablement()
    67     if bqhopper_breg_value == 0:
    68         # BREG value of 0 will use the legacy, local SQLite
    69         # metadata solution or shipped metadata.

File c:\Users\user\OneDrive\python311\Lib\site-packages\bqapi\session_singleton.py:73, in get_session_singleton(settings)
    70 # see if we already have a blp api session created for this cache key
    71 if key not in _instances:
    72     # create a new blp api session, store it in the cache with key
---> 73     _instances[key] = Session(**(settings or {}))
    75 return _instances[key]

File c:\Users\user\OneDrive\python311\Lib\site-packages\bqapi\session.py:93, in Session.__init__(self, event_loop, **settings)
    68 def __init__(self, event_loop=None, **settings):
    69     """Constructor for :class:`Session` instances.
    70 
    71     After constructing a Session object, the session is automatically started
(...)
    91         Session settings. See the :class:`Settings` class for more details.
    92     """
---> 93     self.event_loop = event_loop or get_default_event_loop()
    95     self._settings = Settings(**settings)
    96     self._logger = logging.getLogger('bqapi.Session')

File c:\Users\user\OneDrive\python311\Lib\site-packages\bqapi\event_loop.py:518, in get_default_event_loop()
    516 global _default_loop
    517 if not _default_loop:
--> 518     _ipython_loop = _get_ipython_event_loop()
    519     if _ipython_loop:
    520         _default_loop = EventLoop(
    521             external_loop=TornadoEventLoop(_ipython_loop))

File c:\Users\user\OneDrive\python311\Lib\site-packages\bqapi\event_loop.py:499, in _get_ipython_event_loop()
    492         return None
    494     # Not needed, we are running a ZMQ kernel now...
    495     # kernel = ipython.kernel
    496     # if not isinstance(kernel, IPython.kernel.zmq.ipkernel.IPythonKernel):
    497     #    return None
--> 499     return zmq.eventloop.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    500 except WindowsError:
    501     # Happens when we are in a sandbox and not allowed to load the ZMQ
    502     # native DLL. Treat it like an import error; if ZMQ was supposed to
    503     # be allowed in the sandbox, it should have been imported before
    504     # lowering the token.
    505     return None

AttributeError: module 'zmq.eventloop' has no attribute 'ioloop'`


Suggest you go back to the post you cite, and read the last answer.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

@DS_London this is not a complete solution for what I want, I am familiar with Gilbert's work I use it already for non-BQL, blpapi work in python. Thanks

Thanks @furas sorry for incomplete post. Updated with full traceback.

"this is not a complete solution for what I want" Do you need something other than the ability to run bql queries and get results in a dataframe? It's easier to use the blp package than handle the underlying blpapi directly and parse the json.

I guess I can use the blp package's bql method, though what I want to do is use the full functionality of bql that exists in the Terminal's BQNT Jupyter environment and not the "get() for()" string syntax only.
E.g. you can write something like: bq.data.px_last(dates=bq.func.range('-1m','0d')).zscore().last(1) versus the "get() for()" if you are familiar and understand what I mean.
It seems too difficult to "unsandbox" the packages so maybe blp's solution is best for now unfortunately.

As an aside, pretty neat how Gilbert wrote that script for BQL, as I couldn't find anything about BQL in the core developer guide

blp only uses the basic sendQuery operation of the //blp/bqlsvc service. Other operations and services are available (eg sendExecuteRequest which is a much more complex schema). It looks like data.px_last() and func.range() could be client-side wrappers which construct the basic BQL request, rather than operations which are carried out on the server. Maybe look into the code? I'm not enabled for BQUANT, so can't check I'm afraid.

Interesting point, thanks. I'm not sure if it's client-side, I'd have to dig into the package files that get installed with BQNT.  Appreciate the comments no less. No enablement, you must be sell-side :) You're not missing much ... I only wanted to use it to not blow out my limits with a specific script I'm writing, otherwise as you suggested blp or pdblp work great.

Guess may be has to do with Spyder upgrading from zmq 16.0.0?
Looks like:
Module: zmq.eventloop.ioloop This module is deprecated in pyzmq 17. Use tornado.ioloop.
https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/v26.2.0/api/zmq.eventloop.ioloop.html

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
